# Entity Framework 6.1.2 Many to Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having trouble with entity framework 6.1.2. I'm sure this will have been covered before but I cant find it anywhere. On building the database entity framework wont create the relationships for the two list items I have because I have them declared as single entities above.

Is there any work around for this?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public TeamMember LeadPartner { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public List<TeamMember> OtherTeamMembers { get; set; }
    public List<Team> OtherTeams { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry if this has been asked before I really couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: I am a bit unclear on what you are asking. What relationships specifically would you like exist that don't currently?

Comment: Are you saying that you want Entity framework to have generate a foreign key on the table that houses `SomeClass` to `TeamMember` for the LeadPartner field and a foreign key on the `TeamMember` table to the `SomeClass` table as well?

Comment: Also, what does your configuration for this entity look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely there is ambiguity in the other classes. For instance if you have a `List<SomeClass>` defined in `Team`, EF can't be sure whether this property is to partner with `public Team Team` (which would create a one-many relationship) or `public List<Team> OtherTeams` (creating a many-many relationship). Either is valid.

To resolve the ambiguity, add an `[InverseProperty("OtherTeams")]` annotation to the `List<SomeClass>` in the other classes.

Also, best practice is to expose the property as an `ICollection<T>` rather than a `List<T>`, creating a `new List<T>` or whatever in the constructor. This allows you to vary implementation later, for instance use a `HashSet<T>` instead.

Comment: You have the option of using annotations or the fluent API to configure the entities. Also, using `ICollection<T>` will let entity framework generate proxy classes for your POCO entity types if you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Add the mapping in your `DbContext.OnModelCreating` override similar to the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
            .HasMany<TeamMember>(sc => sc.OtherTeamMembers)
            .HasMany();
         // .HasMany(tm => tm.SomeClassNavigationPropertyList);
```